# How do I reverse this formula which creates a spherical coordinate?

Tags: math, three.js

I have a formula that maps a random point in space to a point that sits in a sphere. I want to be able to reverse this formula to get the random point in space again.

My `unspherize()` function below is not working. Please show me the correct way to reverse the form.

```
function spherize(x,y,z){
  var d = 1 / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2));
  x *= d;
  y *= d;
  z *= d;
  return {x: x, y: y, z: z}
}

function unspherize(x,y,z){
  var d = 1 * Math.pow(Math.sqrt(x) + Math.sqrt(y) + Math.sqrt(z), 2)
  x /= d;
  y /= d;
  z /= d;
  return {x: x, y: y, z: z}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of points that get mapped to the same point on the sphere (e.g., for every (x,y,z) the point (2x,2y,2z) gets mapped to the same vector). Therefore, if you don't save the vector length d, the operation is not reversible.

Answer (score 0):

Using `r` as the radius or Euclidean norm of the point `(x,y,z)`,

```
x /= 1+r
y /= 1+r
z /= 1+r
```

gives you a point inside the sphere. Since this transformation is bijective, it can be reversed, for any point inside the sphere, the "unspherized" point is obtained as

```
x/= 1-r
y/= 1-r
z/= 1-r
```